# Coding beginner needing assistance

Tags: javascript, html, validation, error-handling

I'm brand new to coding. I've created a form with three fields- two with "number" types and one with radio button selection. I'm trying to utilize "try catch throw" to validate these fields and have error messages echoed onto the screen (not as an alert). I know that there is a lot of code in here, but I am really lost with this. Here is my HTML and js:

HTML:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="hshld" class="formhdr">Total number of people in your household:</label>
        <input type="number"  id="hshld" name="hshld" min="1">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="hrrisk" class="formhdr">Number of high-risk people in your household:</label>
        <input type="number"  id="hrrisk" name="hrrisk" min="0">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend class="formhdr">Number of weeks in isolation:</legend>
        <input type="radio" id="countone" name="headcount">
        <label for="countone" class="numweeks">1</label>
        <input type="radio" id="counttwo" name="headcount">
        <label for="counttwo" class="numweeks">2</label>
        <input type="radio" id="countthree" name="headcount">
        <label for="countthree" class="numweeks">3</label>
        <input type="radio" id="countfour" name="headcount">
        <label for="countfour" class="numweeks">4+</label>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

and my .js:

```
//Global variables
    var hshld = document.getElementById("hshld");
    var mysubmit = document.getElementById("submit");
    var radioError = document.getElementById("radioError");
    var weekCount;

//this function checks to see if the user entered a number into the field
    function validatehshld() {
        try {
            if (hshld.value == "") {
                throw "Enter a number!";
            }
            hshld.style.outline = "none";
            // clear input box
        }
        catch (hshldError) {
            hshld.style.outline = "2.5px dashed red";
            hshld.placeholder = hshldError;
            return false;
        }
    }

// makes sure that the radio button is selected. If not, throws an error message into the "radioError" paragraph at under the form.
    function validatewkCount() {
        try {
            if (weekCount == 0) {
                throw document.getElementById('radioError').innerHTML = "Select a number!";
                    }
// clear input box
                    hshld.style.outline = "none"; 
                    }
                    catch (weekCountError) {
                        radioError.style.outline = "2.5px dashed red";
                        radioError.placeholder = radioError;
                        return false;
                    }
    }

// stop the form from submitting if a field needs attention
    function endEvent() {
        return event.preventDefault();
    }

    function validateSubmit() {
        if(validatehshld() === false && validatewkCount() === false) {
            endEvent();
        }
    }

// EventListeners, includes IE8 compatibility
        if (hshld.addEventListener) {
            hshld.addEventListener("focusout", validatehshld, false);
        } else if (hshld.attachEvent) {
        hshld.attachEvent("onclick", validatehshld);
        }

// runs validateSubmit() function when the user clicks the submit button
        if (mysubmit.addEventListener) {
            mysubmit.addEventListener("click", validateSubmit, false);
        } else if (mysubmit.attachEvent) {
            mysubmit.attachEvent("onclick", validateSubmit);
        }

        if (mysubmit.addEventListener) {
            mysubmit.addEventListener("click", numBottles, false);
        } else if (mysubmit.attachEvent) {
            mysubmit.attachEvent("onclick", numBottles);
        }

// this function gets called via the onclick attribute (line 44)
    function numBottles() {

// takes the current value of the input field from id "hshld"
        var people = document.getElementById("hshld").value;
        var hrrisk = document.getElementById("hrrisk").value;

        // this variable represents the number of gallons a single person should have for one week of isolation- 1 gallon per day
        var weekWater = 7; 

        // this variable will hold the number of weeks selected from the radio buttons
        var weekCount;

// this code determines which radio button is selected and assigns a value to the variable depending on which radio button is selected
        if (document.getElementById('countone').checked) {
            var weekCount = 1; 
        } else if (document.getElementById('counttwo').checked) {
            var weekCount = 2;
        } else if (document.getElementById('countthree').checked) {
            var weekCount = 3;
        } else if (document.getElementById('countfour').checked) {
            var weekCount = 4;
        } else if (isNaN(weekCount) === true) {
            var weekCount = 0; 
        }

// echo out the calculation (people X weekWater) to the span object with id=bottles
                document.getElementById("bottles").innerHTML = (people * weekWater * weekCount) + (hrrisk * weekCount);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use `try`, `catch`, or `throw` here, instead create your error message in a new element and place it in the html somewhere you think it looks nice.

I would just use:

```
if (typeof hshld.value !== 'number') { // if a wrong data type was entered

    document.getElementById("error-zone").innerHTML += "<div>Enter a number!</div"

} else {

    // continue calculating answer

}
```

for the quick and dirty method.